# No signing certificate "iOS Development" found

Tags: ios

when I download the developer certificate from apple account and double click so he is not showing a private key in the keychain access.

Comment: You need a private key.  Merely downloading the certificate is not enough.

Comment: if that is urgent, then help yourself and go back to the [roots](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/) of dealing with certificates (by Apple).

Comment: there is any way that I retrieve my private key

Comment: "there is any way that I retrieve my private key" Retrieve it from where?

Comment: I was getting this exact error message when trying to build my Dev scheme. What solved it for me is checking "Automatically manage signing" in my Prod scheme. Go figure...

Answer (score 0):

you need to export certificate from which mac you create it. other wise you need to create new one. no other option ti get private key from developer.apple.com site.

Comment: when i trying to create another one so the message showing that you "Maximum number of certificates generated"

Comment: you need to revoke previous one so it allows to create new one.

Comment: there is 3 certificates are created...I am revoke one and then I try to create new the same message is showing

Comment: you have delete right certificate? if problem is you delete other one then that also give you error..

Comment: you certificate is created?

Comment: @shubham.kaushik There is no need to revoke a Development certificate; just make a new one. You can have as many as you like. The problem only arises with a Distribution certificate, and you said that's not what we're dealing with here.